# EF one to one relation change entity with another (substitute)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have problem to change entity one to one with another:

Here is my test classes:

```
public class MyUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual MyAddress MyAddress { get; set; }
}

public class MyAddress
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public virtual MyUser MyUser { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyAddress>().HasOptional(x => x.MyUser).WithRequired(x => x.MyAddress);
```

In DB i have

```
MyUser ID = "abc", Name = "Test"
MyAddress ID = "abc", AddressLine = "TestAddress"
MyAddress ID = "dfg", AddressLine = "TestAddress2"
```

No I want to remove from MyAddress from MyUser where they have same ID, and to add to MyUser a MyAddress that has other ID

```
// myUser.Id = "abc" myUser.MyAddress.Id = "abc"
// myOldAddress.Id = "abc" myOldAddress.MyUser.Id = "abc"
// myNewAddress.Id = "dfg" myNewAddress.MyUser = null
var myUser = repoUser.GetById("abc")
var myOldAddress = repoAddress.GetById("abc");
myOldAddress.MyUser = null;
var myNewAddress = repoAddress.GetById("dfg");
myUser.MyAddress = myNewAddress;
myNewAddress.MyUser = myUser;
//on save I have this exception and what result i want to have
// myUser.Id = "abc" myUser.MyAddress.Id = "abc"
// myOldAddress.Id = "hjk" myOldAddress.MyUser = null
// myNewAddress.Id = "abc" myNewAddress.MyUser.Id = "abc"
// something like this (substitute)

Exception:
Additional information: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: 
A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be 
changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the
 association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not
 marked for deletion.

{"A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property
 that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the 
dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's 
principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion."}
```

Why EF doesn't change ID automatically to be the same as UserId? User must have Address 1:1, but Address has optional User 1:0

Comment: what about ur database, does userId in address table allow null?

Comment: address can has null user, but user can't has address null, I want to disconnect old address and to change it to another new

Comment: I understand your design, my question is about your database. the exception indicates that address.userId does not allow null

Comment: in DB there is no address.userId because there is one to one, they both (user x address) have same ID, there is no foreign key, you can see in question what is in DB

Comment: so, for you address table, there is Id and addressline. does Id field allow null?

Comment: not allow null, and EF doesn't give me permission to change it ID to new one, and EF doesn't change it atomaticly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, I am not convinced with the design where relation between User
>   and Address is one-to-one, neither allowing addresses without users
>   while not allowing users without addresses. Because usually a typical user can has many addresses

---

However, as per our discussion in the comments section, I got the following:

Your Address table in database has 2 columns: 
`ID` **that does not allow null** and `AddressLine`

So, when you call `myOldAddress.MyUser = null;` in your code
You simply till EF to set `Address.Id` to `null` in database which violate the DB constraint

One solution, *that I don't recommend* is to let `Address.Id` to allow `null`

But I recommend to change the design to one of the following:

- Identify your address table with a separate unique key other than UserId
- create a column to hold the related userId and make it allow null

**So your Address table will be as follows:**

```
ID (not null)
AddressLine 
UserId (Nullable) forieng key in User Table
```

This way you can set `MyAddress.MyUser` to `null` in your code, safely

Comment: okey, i got your point, i think problem is in not allow null but EF  is trying to set it null, i will try to change design in future to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the code samples, myOldAddress.MyUser property is currently not set. Can you try commenting that line out

```
var myUser = repoUser.GetById("abc")
var myOldAddress = repoAddress.GetById("abc");
//myOldAddress.MyUser = null;
var myNewAddress = repoAddress.GetById("dfg");
myUser.MyAddress = myNewAddress;
```

Since user field is optional on the address entity, if you did not set it before, there is no need to set it to null.

Comment: myOldAddress.MyUser I'm using back reference so is set, I updated my question with more data, so you will understand better my problem